# Sequentially running an external independent process using Tkinter and python

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

**BACKGROUND :**
*I'm creating a batch simulation job chooser + scheduler using Tkinter (Portable PYscripter, python v2.7.3)
*This program will function as a front end, to a commercial solver program
*The program needs to allow the user to choose a bunch of files to simulate, sequentially, one after the other. 
*It also needs to have the facility to modify (Add/delete) jobs from an existing/running job list.
*Each simulation will definitely run for several hours. 
*The output of the simulation will be viewed on separate programs and I do not need any pipe to the output. The external viewer will be called from the GUI, when desired.

***I have a main GUI window, which allows the user to : 
    choose job files, submit jobs, view the submission log, stop running jobs(one by one)
The above works well. 
 
 **PROBLEMS :**
*If I use subprocess.Popen("command") : all the simulation input files are launched at the same time. It MUST be sequential (due to license and memory limitations)

*If I use subprocess.call(" ") or the wait() method, then the GUI hangs and there is no scope to stop/add/modify the job list. Even if the  "job submit" command is on an independent window, both the parent windows hang untill the job completes.

**QUESTION 1 :**
*How do I launch the simulation jobs sequentially (like subprocess.call) AND allow the main GUI window to function for the purpose of job list modification or stopping a job ? 
The jobs are in a list, taken using "askopenfilenames" and then run using a For loop.

Relevant parts of the Code :

```
cfx5solvepath=r"c:\XXXX"
def file_chooser_default(): 
    global flist1
    flist1=askopenfilename(parent = root2, filetypes =[('.def', '*.def'),('All', '*.*'),('.res', '*.res')], title ="Select Simulation run files...", multiple = True)[1:-1].split('} {')

def ext_process():
    o=list(flist1)
    p=list(flist1)
    q=list(flist1)
    i=0
    while i < len(flist1):
        p[i]='"%s" -def "%s"'%(cfx5solvepath,flist1[i])
        i+=1
    i=0
    while i < len(p):
        q[i]=subprocess.call(p[i])
        i+=1

root2 = Tk()
root2.minsize(300,300)
root2.geometry("500x300")
root2.title("NEW WINDOW")
frame21=Frame(root2, borderwidth=3, relief="solid").pack()
w21= Button(root2,fg="blue", text="Choose files to submit",command=file_chooser_default).pack()
w2a1=Button(root2,fg="white", text= 'Display chosen file names and order', command=lambda:print_var(flist1)).pack()
w2b1= Button (root2,fg="white", bg="red", text="S U B M I T", command=ext_process).pack()
root2.mainloop()
```

Please let me know if you require anything else. Look forward to your help.

******EDIT ******  
On incorporating the changes suggested by @Tim , the GUI is left free. Since there is a specific sub-program associated with the main solver program to stop the job, I am able to stop the job using the right command.

Once the currently running job is stopped, the next job on the list starts up, automatically, as I was hoping.

This is the code used for stopping the job :

```
def  stop_select(): #Choose the currently running files which are to be stopped
    global flist3
    flist3=askdirectory().split('} {')

def sim_stop(): #STOP the chosen simulation
    st=list(flist3)
    os.chdir("%s"%flist3[0])
    st= subprocess.call('"%s" -directory "%s"'%(defcfx5stoppath,flist3[0]))
    ret1=tkMessageBox.showinfo("INFO","Chosen simulation stopped successfully")
    os.chdir("%s" %currentwd)
```

**QUESTION 2 :** 
*Once the above jobs are Completed, using start_new_thread, the GUI doesn't respond. The GUI works while the jobs are running in the background. But the [start_new_thread](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread) documentation says that the thread is supposed to exit silently when the function returns.

*Additionally, I have a HTML log file that is written into/updated as each job completes. When I use start_new_thread ,the log file content is visible only AFTER all the jobs complete. The contents, along with the time stamps are however correct. Without using start_new_thread, I was able to refresh the HTML file to get the updated submission log.

***On exiting the GUI program using the Task manager several times, I am suddenly unable to use the start_new_thread function !! I have tried reinstalling PYscripter and restarting the computer as well. I can't figure out anything sensible from the traceback, which is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 532, in write
File "C:\Portable Python 2.7.3.1\App\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 439, in _async_request
seq = self._send_request(handler, args)
File "C:\Portable Python 2.7.3.1\App\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 229, in _send_request
self._send(consts.MSG_REQUEST, seq, (handler, self._box(args)))
File "C:\Portable Python 2.7.3.1\App\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 244, in _box
if brine.dumpable(obj):
File "C:\Portable Python 2.7.3.1\App\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\brine.py", line 369, in dumpable
return all(dumpable(item) for item in obj)
File "C:\Portable Python 2.7.3.1\App\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\brine.py", line 369, in <genexpr>
return all(dumpable(item) for item in obj)
File "C:\Portable Python 2.7.3.1\App\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\brine.py", line 369, in dumpable
return all(dumpable(item) for item in obj)
File "C:\Portable Python 2.7.3.1\App\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\brine.py", line 369, in <genexpr>
return all(dumpable(item) for item in obj)
File "C:\Portable Python 2.7.3.1\App\Python_Working_folder\v350.py", line 138, in ext_process
q[i]=subprocess.call(p[i])
File "C:\Portable Python 2.7.3.1\App\lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "C:\Portable Python 2.7.3.1\App\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Portable Python 2.7.3.1\App\lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a separate thread for the job launching. The simplest way would be to use the [`start_new_thread`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread) method from the `thread` module.

Change the submit button's command to `command=lambda:thread.start_new_thread(ext_process, ())`

You will probably want to disable the button when it's clicked and enable it when the launching is complete. This can be done inside `ext_process`.

It becomes more complicated if you want to allow the user to cancel jobs. This solution won't handle that.

Comment: @Shreyas: No problem. Was there anything else you needed answering? If not, and you are happy with this answer, please [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: :I just noticed, the GUI program hangs once the process is complete!